# TCL:search and replace a character in string

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I wanted to replace a character in a string, based on pattern matching. The variable value of `temp` is given by the user and may or may not have preceding "m".
But in case it does have a preceeding `m`, I want to replace the character `m` with `"-"`(minus sign).
so if the value of `temp` is `"m40"`, then `temp1` should look like `"-40"`
Here is what i am tried, but it doesn't work well:

```
set temp "m40c"
if {regexp ^m $temp match} {
    regsub m $temp "-" $temp1
    puts $temp1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

regexp, in the abov example is redundant. regsub will replace, if it finds a match. It doesn't throw any error otherwise.

```
% regsub "^m" $temp "-" temp1 
1
% set temp1
-40c
% set temp "xm40c"
xm40c
% regsub "^m" $temp "-" temp2
0
% set temp2
xm40c
%
```

So, something like this may be useful:

```
puts "Original value: $temp"
if {[regsub "^m" $temp "-" temp]} {
    puts "Updated value: $temp"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did tried this code and it works for me ... just missed the [] brackets around regexp.

```
set temp "m40c"
if {[regexp ^m $temp match]} {
regsub m $temp "-" temp1
puts $temp1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can straightaway use the `regsub` command.

```
% set temp "m40c"
m40c
% regsub m $temp - result
1
% set result
-40c
% set temp "40c"
40c
% regsub m $temp - result2
0
% set result2
40c
%
```

Comment: You are missing the anchor.  This will replace the first 'm' found in $temp.

Answer (score 0):

or in one line,

```
set temp [regsub {^\s*m} $temp "-"]
```

if you want to replace M or m ( case insensitive )

```
set temp [regsub -nocase {^\s*m} $temp "-"]
```